# If i have to run cron job every Friday at 10am, is this the rite setting: 0 17 5 * * *

Tags: python, django

If i have to run cron job every Friday at 10am, is this the correct setting: 0 17 5 * * *

[image: Crontab]Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0 10 * * 5` is the correct CRON expression. [Here](https://crontab.guru/#0_10_*_*_5) is a helpful website for creating CRON expressions.